# Calling ngOnInit method from other component

Tags: angular

If I have:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app1',
  templateUrl: './app1.html',
})
export class A implement OnInit {

  ngOnInit() {

  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app2',
  templateUrl: './app2.html',
})
export class B implement OnInit {

  ngOnInit() {

  }
}
```

then how can I call `ngOnInit()` of class B from class A and my template of class B should update(render)?

Comment: Angular calls `ngOnInit()`. Don't try to call it yourself.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: What's your purpose ?

Comment: suppose i have a modal form in Class A and when i submit it then getting updated in Class B, when i refresh browser then only i can see updated or new inserted data through *ngFor but i dont want to refresh browser... this is the problem i am facing... @Wes

Comment: Use NgbModal from ng2-bootstrap for using modals, it provides callbacks to your parent component. Why go all the way to build one if the solution already exists

Comment: To exchange parameters in Angular, use BehaviorSubject, or EventEmitter with @Input/@Output() or even a viewChild but never call onInit(), create your own function.

Wait few minutes, I'll give you the ViewChild approach, which is closest to your case.

Answer (score 2):

Ok So here is the @ViewChild() solution. ViewChild lets you control your child from the parent component. Let's assume you have MyMain.component.ts and MyChild.component.ts (with the name 'MyChildComponent').

In your parent, create a variable : ViewChild(MyChildComponent) childComponent: MyChildComponent. Now you can access your child functions and variables.

Create a function in your parent

```
refreshChild(data) { this.childComponent.refreshFromParent(data); }
```

and another one in your Child

```
refreshFromParent(data) { this.data = data ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

For this you have to make the component B injectable. we use @Injectable() for this and a provider inside it as providedIn: 'root'.

### component A

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app1',
  templateUrl: './app1.html',
})
export class A implement OnInit {
  constructor( private a: A ){}

  ngOnInit() {
      this.a.ngOnInit();
  }
}
```

### component B

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app2',
  templateUrl: './app2.html',
})
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class B implement OnInit {

  ngOnInit() {

  }
}
```

this worked for me, please let me know if this works